# onclick="window.open" issues in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm having a hard time getting this to work in IE. All the other browsers are working perfectly! Can't use a transparent gif because this link is being used inside a cycling background image. If I place a gif, it does not cycle anymore... Anyone suggestions?

```
<div onclick="window.open('mylink.html','new_window');" style="display:block; float:right; height:40px; width:100px; cursor:pointer;">
```

Comment: sad you're not having issues in all browsers...

Comment: Describe what is happening, in detail.

Comment: what IE version are we talking about ?

Comment: I'm creating a Div container so it can look like I'm clicking on a portion of my background image. It all works well except for IE (of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe IE still only fires onClick events from elements that are normally clickable.

Do this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('mylink.html','new_window'); return false" style="display:block; float:right; height:40px; width:100px; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none">
```

(of course use the corresponding `</a>` instead of `</div>` at the end)

Not sure what a transparent gif has to do with it.

Comment: Yep, IE is the only one who didn't work out. Changed my structure and used something similar to what you posted. thx dude!

Comment: I also got burnt for a few minutes by trying to put a hyphen in the window name. Worked everywhere except for IE.

Answer (score 1):

For link, I prefer use the tag `<a>` :

```
<a href="mylink.html" target="_blank" style="display:block; float:right; height:40px; width:100px; cursor:pointer;"> Your link </a>
```

You can even put a picture between `<a> <img .... /> </a>`
Don't forget to add in style : text-decoration:none;

Comment: Had no luck with images because of the jquery image cycle, it picked the <img> out and included it in the cycle portion. Thx for giving some advice Mitch, appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Check your IE settings to see if popups are allowed.

The click event is properly fired in IE 8

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R249t/

Comment: Aiming mostly for IE6... haven't found a solution yet

Comment: Internet Explorer 6 is nearly dead, under 5% market share(in June 2010)... I think that if your script works with IE7 and later you are safe :)

Comment: one last thing :) ... try writing onClick with capital C

Comment: Tried all these, no avail for IE. Thx for helping out guys